# Converting values to JSON grouped by another column

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
currency   number
USD        1
USD        2
USD        3
EUR        1
EUR        5
EUR        6
GBP        1
GBP        7
```

I am trying to convert this into a JSON (Postgres) that is set by each currency, and get an output that looks like this:

```
currency      number
USD           [1,2,3]
EUR           [1,5,6]
GBP           [1,7]
```

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `jsonb_agg()` for that:

```
select currency, jsonb_agg(number order by number) as number
from the_table
group by currency;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using array_agg and array_to_json:

```
select currency, array_to_json(array_agg(number order by number)) as JSONnumber
from Test
group by currency;
```

You can play with it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ab63a/2